# Number guessing game c#. Tie least guesses to best round and vice versa

Tags: c#

I'am super new to coding and this is probably an easy fix but I just dont know how to solve it or what exactly to search for. I'm doing this assignment from school and it's a random number guessing game. In this assignment they want to know which round was the best round.

The problem I have is that I want to implement a sort of a round tracker and simultaneously tie the best/worst amount of guesses to the best/worst round the user guessed.

I hope I'am being clear with what I'm asking, I don't know the coding language too well.

This is what I've done so far and I just can't tie the "int min_tries/max_tries" to a specific round number.

```
else
  {
   BestRound.Add(tries);
   RoundNumber.Add(rounds);
   totaltries++;
   tries++;
   Console.WriteLine();
   Console.WriteLine(guess + " is correct. You win! It took you " + tries + " tries to guess right!");

   Console.WriteLine();

   Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? Yes/No?");
   playAgain = Console.ReadLine();

  if (playAgain.Equals("Yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
   reset = true;
  }
  else
  {
   reset = false;
  }
  }

  if (attempt >= totalattemtp)
  {
   BestRound.Add(tries);
   RoundNumber.Add(rounds);
   Console.WriteLine("!GAME OVER!");
   Console.WriteLine("You have have no attempts left.");
  
   Console.WriteLine();

   Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? Yes/No?");
   playAgain = Console.ReadLine();

  if (playAgain.Equals("Yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
   reset = true;
  }
  else
  {
   reset = false;
  }
  break;
  }
  

 }
}

int max_tries = BestRound.AsQueryable().Max();
int min_tries = BestRound.AsQueryable().Min();
int best_round = RoundNumber.AsQueryable().Min();
int worst_round = RoundNumber.AsQueryable().Max();

if(BestRound.AsQueryable().Max() == 10)
{
  max_tries = 10 - 1;

   Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing! Your total tries where " + totaltries + ".");
   Console.WriteLine("Your best round was number " + best_round + " and had " + (min_tries + 1) + " tries."); 
   Console.WriteLine("Your worst round was round number " + worst_round + " and had " + (max_tries + 1) + " tries.");
}
else
{
   //thanking user for playing and keeping program running until random key-input. 
   Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing! Your total tries where " + totaltries + ".");
   Console.WriteLine("Your best round was number " + best_round + " and had " + (min_tries + 1) + " tries."); 
   Console.WriteLine("Your worst round was round number " + worst_round + " and had " + (max_tries + 1) + " tries.");
}

Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what's confusing you?  In particular, I'm not following what you mean by, "I just can't tie the "int min_tries/max_tries" to a specific round number".

Comment: It would have been useful for you to include the types of things like `BestRound` and `RoundNumber` (btw, RoundNumber isn't a great name for something that seems to be a collection). Consider creating a class like `RoundInfo` that has three integer properties: RoundNumber, Tries, & NumberToGuess). Create a new one after every round, and add the new entry to something like `List<RoundInfo> RoundsInformation`. Now you have nice structured data you can query

Comment: Hi @KirkWoll, thank you for answering my question. Okey, I will try to explain it better. Lets say my teacher plays 5 times (''rounds''), (Round 1 it takes him 3 guesses. Round 2, 5 guesses. Round 3, 8 guesses. Round 4, 2 guesses. Round 5, 6 guesses.), when he don't want to play anymore I want the stats showing how many total guesses he did during his 5 game and what his best round and worst round was, in this example :Best round was round 4 with 2 guesses and worst round was round 3 with 8 guesses. But I can't tie the right guesses to the right round. I hope I'm being a little bit more clear.

Comment: Hi @Flydog57 thank you for answering my question. BestRound and RoundNumber are int lists, if that's what I should have included? I'm sorry, I don't want to come off as rude, but I'm super, super new to coding. I have studied for about max. 14 days. So I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not to familiar with coding language. Please tell me if I don't understand you correctly, but RoundInfo is a list that holds more integer so I can add number of guesses to a specifik round played?

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you so much! Now I get it, this was outside of my knowledge, very useful! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was talking about in the comments.

Create a simple *POCO* ("Plain old CLR object") class named `RoundInfo` to hold the results of a *round*:

```
internal class RoundInfo
{
    public int RoundNumber { get; set; }
    public int NumTries { get; set; }
    public int NumberToGuess { get; set; }

    public RoundInfo(int roundNumber, int numTries, int numberToGuess)
    {
        RoundNumber = roundNumber;
        NumTries = numTries;
        NumberToGuess = numberToGuess;
    }
}
```

It's just three properties and a convenience constructor.

Now to plug it into a guessing game... Here's a guessing game I threw together:

```
var random = new Random();
var round = 1;
var timeToQuit = false;
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Guessing Game");
var roundsInformation = new List<RoundInfo>();

while (!timeToQuit) {
    var numToGuess = random.Next(10) + 1;
    var guess = -1;
    var tries = 1;
    Console.WriteLine($"Round {round}:");
    while (true)
    {
        guess = GetNumberFromUser("Enter a guess between 1 and 10", 1, 10);
        if (guess == numToGuess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Congratulation, you guessed correctly in {tries} tries");

            // Here is where I add the result from this round into the list of round information
            roundsInformation.Add(new RoundInfo(round, tries, numToGuess));

            Console.Write("Is it time to Quit (Y/N): ");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (response.Equals("Y", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || response.Equals("Yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                timeToQuit = true;
            }
            break;      //from the inner "while(true)" 
        }
        ++tries;
    }
    ++round;
}
```

Then, once the user has quit, I simply sort the list of round information (using LINQ's `orderby`) to show him/her the results:

```
var sortedResults = (from result in roundsInformation orderby result.NumTries select result).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Here are your results (Best to worst):");
foreach (var result in sortedResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Round {result.RoundNumber}, trying to guess: {result.NumberToGuess}, {result.NumTries} tries");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Note that I call `GetNumberFromUser` to get the number from the user.  I like to do my UI checking outside the main logic of the program.  Here is that method:

```
static int GetNumberFromUser(string prompt, int min, int max)
{
    while (true) {
        Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
        var read = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(read, out var number) && number >= min && number <= max){
            return number;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Entered data must be an integer between {min} and {max} inclusive");
    }
}
```

If I run this program, I get something like this in the console:

```
Welcome to the Guessing Game
Round 1:
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 1
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 0
Entered data must be an integer between 1 and 10 inclusive
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 2
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 11
Entered data must be an integer between 1 and 10 inclusive
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 3
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 4
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: abc
Entered data must be an integer between 1 and 10 inclusive
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 5
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 6
Congratulation, you guessed correctly in 6 tries
Is it time to Quit (Y/N): n
Round 2:
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 1
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 2
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 3
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 4
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 5
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 6
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 7
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 8
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 9
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 10
Congratulation, you guessed correctly in 10 tries
Is it time to Quit (Y/N): n
Round 3:
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 2
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 3
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 5
Congratulation, you guessed correctly in 3 tries
Is it time to Quit (Y/N): n
Round 4:
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 1
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 2
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 3
Enter a guess between 1 and 10: 4
Congratulation, you guessed correctly in 4 tries
Is it time to Quit (Y/N): y
Here are your results (Best to worst):
Round 3, trying to guess: 5, 3 tries
Round 4, trying to guess: 4, 4 tries
Round 1, trying to guess: 6, 6 tries
Round 2, trying to guess: 10, 10 tries
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it! :D