# I'm trying to write a simple program that picks a random number between 1 and 10 and gives the user to guess it

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop, console-application

I'm new to C# and I'm struggling a bit with loops.
For this one, I'm trying to use the 'for' loop. I have tried various options - for, while loops, but I wasn't able to reach the desired result.

For this one, the says I lost, even if I "guessed" the number.

```
{
    var random = new Random();
    int random2 = Convert.ToInt32(random.Next(0, 10));

    Console.WriteLine(random2);


    for  (var i = 4; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number from 0 to 10:");
        var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (input != random2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have {0} tries left.", i - 1);
            continue;

        }

        if (input != random2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have {0} tries left.", i - 1);
            continue;
        }

        if (input != random2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have only {0} try left!!", i - 1);
            continue;
        }

        if (input == random2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You lose!!!");
            break;
        }

        if (input == random2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have won!!!!!");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do: write a program that picks a random number between 1 and 10 and gives the user 4 chances to guess it. However, I want to make the console print the remaining number of tries and print a different message when the user is on their last try.

Comment: Consider learning how to use the debugger - you might spot your error very easily.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: `for  (var i = 4; i <= 4; i++)` will only execute once.

Comment: Here's a full featured random number guessing game (my answer). You can pull some ideas from it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993564/number-guessing-game-c-tie-least-guesses-to-best-round-and-vice-versa/71022065#71022065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's implement from scratch step by step:

1. Let's start from comments (what we are going to do)
2. Let's use proper names (`attempt` instead of `i`)

```
// Computer pick the number in 1..9 range
int picked = Random.Shared.Next(1, 10);
// We have 4 attempts
int attempts = 4;

// We haven't found the picked number yet
bool found = false;

// for each attempt
for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= attempts; ++attempt) {
  // We are asked to guess
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number in 1 .. 9 range:");

  // We do our guess - note, int.TryParse is a better option
  int guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

  // If we guess right then ...
  if (guess == picked) {
    // ... the picked number is found and  
    found = true;
    // we don't want any attempt more
    break; 
  }

  // if we don't guess right, show number of attempts 
  Console.WriteLine($"You have {attempts - attempt + 1} tries left.");
} 

// after all attempts show outcome
if (found)
  Console.WriteLine("You have won!!!!!");
else
  Console.WriteLine("You have lost.");
```